# What is wrong with this sorting of dictionary?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort the dictionary here:

```
car =   {
  "brand": ["Ford","Honda","Toyota","Tesla","Ford"],
  "model": ["Mustang","CRV","RAV4","X","Transit"],
  "year": [1964,2010,2015,2022,1964],
  "color": ["Red","Yellow","Green","Blue","Black"]
}

sortedbyval1={k: v for k, v in sorted(car.items(),key=lambda v:v[1])}
```

I keep getting error message like below. There is no `<` in the code!!!

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

I am trying to sort the car dictionary by model, year, color etc.

If possible, by color AND year.

Comment: The sorted function uses cooperation operations. And you are trying to sort two different data types.

Comment: Exactly what it's telling you; `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`. They are different types and, since Python 3, it's not possible to order a mixed collection of them

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that a car is made up of one element from each key? So `car["brand"][0]`, `car["model"][0]`, etc is one car? If so, consider transposing that data so that you have a list of dictionaries rather than a dictionary of lists. The format you have it in is going to be very difficult to consume, which is probably why you're running into awkwardness with Python built-in functions not built for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have a dictionary of a bunch of car attributes, not a collection of cars. That's why when you use `key=lambda v:v[1]`, `sorted` is trying to compare lists that contain different types. For example, "year" only contains ints, yet you want to compare it with "brand" which contains strings, so you get the TypeError.

You could rework that dictionary to create a list of cars. Assuming the same index value corresponds to the same car, you can iterate over the `zip`ped `car.values()` and create a list of dictionaries using the dict constructor where each dictionary is a car.

Then use `list.sort` where the sorting key is by model, year and color to sort the list of cars.

```
list_of_cars = [dict(zip(car.keys(), tpl)) for tpl in zip(*car.values())]
list_of_cars.sort(key=lambda car: (car['model'], car['year'], car['color']))
```

Output:

```
>>> print(list_of_cars)
[{'brand': 'Honda', 'model': 'CRV', 'year': 2010, 'color': 'Yellow'},
 {'brand': 'Ford', 'model': 'Mustang', 'year': 1964, 'color': 'Red'},
 {'brand': 'Toyota', 'model': 'RAV4', 'year': 2015, 'color': 'Green'},
 {'brand': 'Ford', 'model': 'Transit', 'year': 1964, 'color': 'Black'},
 {'brand': 'Tesla', 'model': 'X', 'year': 2022, 'color': 'Blue'}]
```

Comment: @Arpit `dict.items` returns tuples where the second elements are the values which are lists here. You can access a list by its index, so you can sort it as: `dict(sorted(word_freq.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1][1], x[1][2], x[1][3])))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this beauty:

```py
car = {
  "brand": [ "Ford", "Honda", "Toyota", "Tesla", "Ford" ],
  "model": [ "Mustang", "CRV", "RAV4", "X", "Transit" ],
  "year":  [ 1964, 2010, 2015, 2022, 1964 ],
  "color": [ "Red", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Black" ]
}

criteria = "model";

sorted_dict = {
    k: v for k, v in [
        (a, [
            car[a][b] for b in [
                c for (c, _) in sorted(
                    zip(
                        [
                            c for c in range(0, len(car[criteria]) )
                        ], 
                        car[criteria]
                    ), 
                    key = lambda x: x[1]
                )
            ]
        ]) for a in car.keys()
    ]
};

print(sorted_dict)
```

Hope it helps! (Don't forget to click the green tick if this is what you wanted :D)

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly what you asked for but since you are learning python, one might mention the clean and simple way of using classes and object oriented programming in this case:

```py
class car():

    def __init__(self, brand, model, year, color):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.color = color


cars = [car("Ford", "Mustang", 1964, "Red"),
        car("Honda", "CRV", 2010, "Yellow"),
        car("Toyota", "RAV4", 2015, "Green"),
        car("Tesla", "X", 2022, "Blue"),
        car("Ford", "Transit", 1964, "Black")]

cars.sort(key=lambda c: c.year)

for c in cars:
    print(c.year, c.model, c.brand)
```